# SSRS report - PageName of the tablix is ignored when no rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working with SSRS report project in Visual Studio. I set a PageName property of the tablix to a desirable name. But, in case when there is no rows, this property is ignored and in Excel I see "Sheet1" instead. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: I just tested this and I am unable to reproduce what you are asking about. When I have a blank tablix it exports to excel in a blank sheet with the appropriate name.

Comment: It generates a "Sheet 1" name in case when NoRowsMessage property is not empty. When it is empty it works as expected. But, in my case, I need NoRowsMessage too.

Comment: Try putting the tablix in a rectangle. Set the page name property on the rectangle. This will allow the NoRowsMessage to appear and the sheet name will be set by the rectangle since the tablix property is ignored in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

see if this link can be of help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx